# Уникальный хеш на больше 8 миллионов строк

Tags: c#, алгоритм, хеширование

Есть база с огромным количеством строк. Все строки уникальны. Содержат в себе английские, русские буквы и цифры, могут содержать спецсимволы. В строке от 1 до N слов.
Вопрос: как можно для каждого сделать уникальный хеш?
Использование `long` возможно, но необходимо вписаться в рамки `int`.
Описываться алгоритм будет на c#, по идее для ускорения можно использовать asm, но над этим думаем.

Comment: Гарантированно уникальный - слабо верится :)

Если надо вписаться в `int` - ну, я бы подумал о вычислении CRC32...

Comment: @Harry задача имеет место жить и быть, только потому что в условии её - уникальные строки.

Comment: @Harry с коллегами думаем несколько дней. на тестах около 10т строк дубликатов около 2 процентов. Это печально...

Comment: Ну, если вам так нужно гарантированная уникальность - то сделайте словарь, перенумеровав все строки, и хеш тогда будет просто номером строки. Уникальность гарантируется :)

Comment: @Harry скорость

Comment: Ну вы же понимаете, что как минимум нет же никакой абсолютно гарантии, что новая добавленная строка, *не совпадая ни с одной из имеющихся*, будет иметь отличный от прочих хэш. Я не могу, как говорится, положить что-нибудь на колоду, споря, но уверен, что *простой* хэш для этих строк не получится. И - вот тут я абсолютно уверен - что никакой хэш не обеспечит гарантию несовпадений при добавлении новой строки. И, если не секрет - почему такое жесткое требование уникальности хэша?

Comment: Кажется, вам нужно нечто [вроде `gperf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) (генератора идеальных хэш-функций), но это возможно только если вы заранее знаете все ожидаемые строки.

Comment: в рамках XY проблемы: зачем вам нужен этот хэш?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Допустим, у нас есть случайная хеш-функция, M возможных ее значений и N элементов. Тогда вероятность, что хеши элементов будут разными, равна **1 × (1 - 1/M) × (1 - 2/M) × ... × (1 - (N-1)/M) = M! / ((M-N)! × M<sup>N</sup>)**. При M = 2<sup>32</sup> и N = 8 000 000 [она будет равна](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4294967296!+%2F+((4294967296-8000000)!+*+4294967296%5E8000000)) 1,75 × 10<sup>-3238</sup>.

Для сравнения - вероятность падения метеорита завтра вам на голову больше, чем вероятность отсутствия коллизий в таких условиях.

Это величина более чем достаточно маленькая чтобы признать перебор хеш-функций в поисках подходящей невозможным.

---

Если строки неизвестны вам заранее - на этом можно закончить. Любая функция, которую бы вы не выбрали, почти наверняка даст коллизии на неизвестном заранее наборе строк.

А вот если строки заранее известны - то алгоритм идеального хеширования для них построить можно. Делается это так:

1. Выбираем число бит для "старшей" части хеша. Число бит h даст **H=2<sup>h</sup>** разных значений.
2. Берем любую хеш-функцию, и делим в соответствии с ней исходные строки по H корзинам. В среднем получим **N1 = N/H** строк в корзине.
3. Для каждой корзины подбираем (автоматически, разумеется) отдельную идеальную хеш-функцию для младших бит хеша. Это будет **M1 = M/H** разных значений.

Чтобы шаг 3 длился адекватное время, величина **M1<sup>2</sup>** должна быть сравнима с **N1**. Получаем - **M<sup>2</sup> / H<sup>2</sup> ∽ N / H** - то есть надо брать H порядка **M<sup>2</sup> / N**.

Получаем H = 16 384 (h = 14), M1 = 288, N1 = 262 144.

Итого, алгоритм получения хеш-фукции будет такой:

1. Считаем хеш-функцию 1 по модулю 16 384, запоминаем в переменной h1.
2. Идем в таблицу, посчитанную заранее, по индексу h1. Получаем параметры для хеш-функции 2.
3. Считаем хеш-функцию 2 по модулю 262 144, запоминаем в переменной h2.
4. Считаем `(h1 << 18) + h2` - это и есть уникальный хеш.

В качестве хеш-функции 2 надо выбрать что-нибудь параметрическое, чтобы было где выбирать случайные параметры. То есть тут неплохо подойдет полиноминальный хеш.

В качестве хеш-функции 1 можно выбрать любую хорошую хеш-функцию.

Алгоритм получается довольно быстрым (asm не нужен) - но потребует константной таблицы килобайт на 32 или 64.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, осталось все переварить подумать и сделать. Строки известны в начале.

Answer (score 4):

**Обратите внимание на комментарий @Harry!!!**

- Гарантированную уникальность можно обеспечить только лишь словарем
- Любые хэш-функции - обеспечивают **лишь** высокую вероятность уникальности

Многие спецы непроизвольно путают предметную область использования вероятностных величин. Если мы работаем с вероятностной величиной, то мы должны, несмотря на величину вероятности, обрабатывать два исхода "сработало" vs "не сработало". В противном случае мы должны указать, что создаваемая подсистема на дает 100% гарантии отказа. Простой пример правильного использования вероятностных величин - алгоритмы сжатия по предсказанию. Нашли часто повторяющиеся последовательности - хорошо, не нашли - **все равно обработали.** Поэтому не нужно "покупаться" на величину, даже столь внушительную, вероятности. Далее шуточный пример ...

**"Упал на голову кирпич"**

Небольшое размышление по поводу вероятностей на простом, можно сказать обыденном событии, которое увы, изредка происходит.
А история такова. Шел мужик по делам возле строийки. На голову упал кирпич. Нет мужика. Какова была вероятность прожить мужику еще немножко?

Постулаты:

- площадь поверхности нашей планеты 510 072 000 км²
- 1км² = 1000000м²
- полщадь суши к площади воды относится примерно 3 к 7
- для постройки жилого 12-этажного кирпичного дома требуется 1854288 кирпичей (считал относительно расчетного для одноэтажного, взял 6 квартир на этаже и 12 этажей, плюс внес поправку на 2/3, типа экономия)
- в году 365*24*60*60 = 31536000 секунд
- с сутках 24*60*60 = 86400 секунд
- у обычного человека будет не более 500 жизненных ситуаций, которые побудят его на то или иное действие
- человек пойдет пешком, если путь его составит не более 2км, иначе воспользуется транспортом
- человек старше 10 лет пойдет самостоятельно, пусть продолжительность жизни 70 лет, тогда 60 лет = 1892160000 секунд

Мужик идет в нужном месте, в нужное время, по нужному делу, срывается нужный кирпич, и в нужный момент совершенно ненужно попадает в голову.
Итак, все события совершаются независимо:

**Теорема умножения вероятностей для независимых событий**

P(AB) = P(A)*P(B) - вероятность одновременного наступления двух независимых событий равна произведению вероятностей этих событий.

Далее расчет на замечательном Ruby:

```
v1 = 510072000000000*3/7 # площадь суши в кв.метрах
v2 = 1854288             # количество кирпичей для постройки 12-этажного дома
v3 = 31536000            # количество секунд в году
v4 = 86400               # количество секунд в сутках
v5 = 500                 # жизненных ситуаций
v6 = 2000                # путь в метрах
v7 = 1892160000          # "самостоятельная жизнь в секундах"   

puts "Сколько было вариантов у мужика выжить: #{v1*v2*v3*v4*v5*v6*v7-1}"
```

Ответ:

```
Сколько вариантов было у мужика выжить: 2089825832201191353090774690693119999999999999999
```

Ну или примерная вероятность такого вот попадания была: 10⁻⁴⁹

Правда практически нереально?

PS. Безусловно все расчеты крайне-крайне приблизителны, цель была осознать порядок малости вероятностной величины.

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос. И Harry не давал ответа.

Comment: Каждую секунду кирпич размером метр на метр выпрыгивает из произвольного места единственного в мире дома и падает в одно и то же место.

Comment: Он посоветовал построить на словаре. Цитирую: "Ну, если вам так нужно гарантированная уникальность - то сделайте словарь, перенумеровав все строки, и хеш тогда будет просто номером строки. Уникальность гарантируется :)"

Comment: Qwertiy, не "каждую" а "в одну из"